# UnAuthorized for Social News Feed data in rest api

Tags: sharepoint-addin, newsfeed, sharepoint-rest-api, social-feed

I have created a custom web part which will get the news feed data using REST API as

```
url: url + "/_api/social.feed/my/timelinefeed"
```

But when I created a SharePoint hosted app for news feed data with the same URL it is not working, It shows `unauthorized error`. But we included permissions for social feed and core, tenant as read and write.

Answer (score 1):

In AppManifest.xml permission list,try to include user profile and site collection scope with read permission.